# Countif function with Multiple logic in one Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Can we use Multiple logic in single criteria in Countif function in VBA?

Example: Col A contains similar names like Joe and Joseph I need the count of these using Countif function, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try wildcards if your criteria follows specific format like:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Jo*")
```

Above will count all entries beginning *Jo*.

Another way is to use *array constant* and incorporate `SUMPRODUCT` function.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A10,{"Joseph","Joe"}))
```

Above counts *Joseph* and *Joe*.
You can also use *Range reference* in place of array constants.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A10,B1:B2))
```

Where `B1:B2` contains your criteria.

Comment: The above functions are working in excel, but can we use the same formula in VBA/Macro?

Comment: @Ganesh Yes. Indeed you can use it in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A3,"Joe") + COUNTIF(A1:A3,"Joseph")
```

Comment: In real data I have four options to count so I need to use four Countif function, is there any better way.

Comment: @Ganesh have you tried the [COUNTIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)?  Note that this function is only available Excel 2007 or later